# extjs 3.2.1 chart is not displaying

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am creating a  pie chart in 3.2.1. and then I am adding this chart into field set. But it is not displaying chart into field set. Only blank white page is displaying. And in console **"Uncaught TypeError: Error #1007"** this error is showing.
Here is my code-

```
 createChart: function(node, fieldSetId, KWTags) {
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['name', 'data'],
        data: [{
            "name": "Item-0",
            "data": 5
        }, {
            "name": "Item-1",
            "data": 7
        }, {
            "name": "Item-2",
            "data": 3
        }, {
            "name": "Item-3",
            "data": 6
        }, {
            "name": "Item-4",
            "data": 2
        }, {
            "name": "Item-5",
            "data": 8
        }]
    });


    var chart = new Ext.chart.Chart({
        width: 200,
        height: 350,
        animate: true,
        store: store,
        theme: 'Base:gradients',
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            angleField: 'data',

            showInLegend: true,
            tips: {
                trackMouse: true,
                width: 140,
                height: 28,

                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {

                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ' ate ' + storeItem.get('data') + ' cookies');

                }
            },
            label: {
                field: 'name',
                display: 'rotate',
                //contrast: true,
                font: '18px Arial'
            }
        }]


    });
    return chart;

},
```